# How to stop Jackson from parsing an empty Json array to the number zero?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, jackson

Take for instance this json string:

```
[1, 2, []]
```

Jackson will parse that empty array as the number 0.

How can I prevent Jackson from doing this and instead give me an empty ArrayNode instance?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When I read the json sting as a tree I`m getting an ArrayNode for the third element. Can you show your code? Since you mentioned Play it could be something Scala specific.

Comment: Without sample code we can only guess...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something else wrong with your set up: Jackson will not coerce arrays to numbers under any conditions I am aware of.